# Read a json file and print output using a PHP script

Tags: php, json

I have to write a script to read a JSON file which will have information about a Data Pipeline - mainly three components - Status, Comments and Timestamp. Once I read the file in JSON, I need to print out the output for that respective Data Pipeline with all the three components. The output would look something like this as below:

Name: Apollo
Status: Pending
Comments: Monthly report
Timestamp: 00:00

I have the following script to generate the JSON file:

```
<?php
    $data = array(
             "name"=>"Apollo", 
             "cob"=> array(
                          status=> "completed",
                          comment=> "Monthly report",
                          timestamp=> "00:00"
                         ),
              );

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I have the following script to read the JSON file generated and to print the above required output:

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents ('./cob_details.json');
    $json = json_decode($data, true);

    echo ('<pre>');
    print_r ($json);
    echo ('</pre>');

    echo ('<br>output:</br>');

    foreach ($json as $key => $value)
    {
    echo "Name: $value Status: $value]<br />";
    }
?>
```

I am particularly new to JSON and PHP....Can you please let me know what am I missing over here in this script to get the required output or where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is actually the problem you encounter? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that your json data generator has a minor error

Try this instead, field names in an array have to be text literals and you forgot to wrap the names in quotes

```
<?php
    $data = array(
             "name" => "Apollo",
             "cob"  => array(
                          'status'    => "completed",
                          'comment'   => "Monthly report",
                          'timestamp' => "00:00"
                         )
              );

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Now the code that read the data needs to loop over the first array and then grab the bits it is interested in from the inner array using the `$value` variable which is the address of the inner array. I am assuming the actual data contains more fields than your sample code so I used a `switch` but an `if` would do if its not that complicated

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents ('./cob_details.json');
    $json = json_decode($data, TRUE);

    echo ('<pre> print the json ');
    print_r ($json);
    echo ('</pre>');

    echo '<br>output:</br>';

    foreach ($json as $key => $value)
    {
        switch ( $key ) {
            case 'name' :
                echo "Name: $value";
                break;
            case 'cob' : 
                echo ' Status: ' . $value['status'] . ']<br />';
                break;
            case 'another field' :
                // and so on
                break;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$data = file_get_contents ('./cob_details.json');
$json = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_array($value)) {
        echo $key . '=>' . $value . '<br/>';
    } else {
        foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
            echo $key . '=>' . $val . '<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```